# Insert com datatime Postgresql e c#

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

Gostaria de tirar uma duvida, porque a primeira data não funciona?

> Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtUltAcesso", "2017-01-01 01:01:01+09");

Erro que retorna:

> Erro ao inserer usuario - Erro: 42804: column "usu_dataacesso" is of
>   type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

E ja essa funciona certo

> Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtCadastro",
>   NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDateTime.Now);

```
 public void insere() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Abre a conexao para insercao
                        abrirConexao();
                        Cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Cadastro\".\"usuario\" (usu_nome,usu_cargo,usu_cpf,usu_dataAcesso,usu_dataCadastro,usu_status,usu_login,usu_senha) values (@nome,@cargo,@cpf,@dtUltAcesso,@dtCadastro,@status,@login,@senha)", Con);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", "Flavio");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo","TI");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", "0101010101");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtUltAcesso", "2017-01-01 01:01:01+09");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtCadastro", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDateTime.Now);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "A");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", "fla");
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", "123");

                        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("Usuario Inserido com Sucesso");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Erro ao inserer usuario - Erro: " + ex.Message);

                    }
```

Mas gostaria de passar uma string coma data, como poderia fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Tentou passar a informação para o banco com aspas simples `''`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você passa a data entre " " ela vai como string e não uma data em si,
o segundo caso funcionou por que foi passado uma data como parametro!
converta sua string para data e tudo ira ocorrer como esperado

```
 Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtUltAcesso",
                  DateTime.ParseExact("2017-01-01 01:01:01+09", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) );
```